# Using SQL to pull prior record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some transactional data in an Oracle database.  Within this table the same id_num can be associated with multiple objects occurring at different dates/times.  I am trying to pull together results using SQL that contain the most recent record for each id_num and also the previous object value.  This screen shot shows an example of the data along with the desired results. I color coded the data to illustrate which rows within the data the result should be pulled from.

I wrote the following, which gets me the most recent record for each id_num, but I am struggling with how to pull in the previous_object.  Really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

[image: data set and desired result]

```
SELECT * FROM 

(
SELECT
  id_num,
  date_time,
  object, 
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id_num ORDER BY date_time DESC) RANK_NUM

FROM TableX

  ) x 

WHERE RANK_NUM = 1
```

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data or results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   id_num
        ,object
        ,date_time
        ,previous_object
from     (
         select   id_num
                 ,object
                 ,max(date_time)                                                      as date_time
                 ,lag(object) over(order by max(date_time))                           as previous_object
                 ,row_number() over(partition by id_num order by max(date_time) desc) as rn
         from     t
         group by id_num, object
         ) t
where    rn = 1
```

| ID_NUM | OBJECT | DATE_TIME | PREVIOUS_OBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1X | C | 27-JUL-22 14.43.00.000000 | B |
| 2X | G | 10-AUG-22 15.36.00.000000 | F |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e30Hlwir?hide=48)